# Python Treeview alternate row colouring after sorting

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way that the alternative row colouring can be maintained after sorting? My treeview has 2,000+ rows and would like to know if there is any solution other than retagging all the rows each time a column is sorted. When you click on any column, the row colouring gets mixed up.

Environment: Python 3.10.0 Windows 21H1

```
import tkinter as objTK
from tkinter import ttk as objTTK
from functools import partial

# Custom column sort for treeview
class MyTreeview(objTTK.Treeview):
    def heading(self, column, sort_by=None, **kwargs):
        if sort_by and not hasattr(kwargs, 'command'):
            func = getattr(self, f"_sort_by_{sort_by}", None)
            if func:
                kwargs['command'] = partial(func, column, False)
            # End of if
        # End of if
        return super().heading(column, **kwargs)
    # End of heading()

    def _sort(self, column, reverse, data_type, callback):
        l = [(self.set(k, column), k) for k in self.get_children('')]
        l.sort(key=lambda t: data_type(t[0]), reverse=reverse)
        for index, (_, k) in enumerate(l):
            self.move(k, '', index)
        # End of for loop
        self.heading(column, command=partial(callback, column, not reverse))
    # End of _sort()

    def _sort_by_name(self, column, reverse):
        self._sort(column, reverse, str, self._sort_by_name)
    # End of _sort_by_num()
# End of class MyTreeview

objWindow = objTK.Tk()

arrlbHeader = ["Type" , "Description"]
treeview = MyTreeview(columns=arrlbHeader, show="headings")
arrRows = [
    ["Expenses", "Gen"],
    ["Expenses", "Aug"],
    ["Expenses", "Aug"],
    ["Income", "Aug"],
    ["Expenses", "Aug"]
]
arrColWidth = [70, 80]
arrColAlignment = ["center", "e"]

# Column header and attributes
arrSortType = ["name", "name"]
for iCount in range(len(arrlbHeader)):
    strHdr = arrlbHeader[iCount]
    treeview.heading(strHdr, text=strHdr.title(), sort_by=arrSortType[iCount])
    treeview.column(arrlbHeader[iCount], width=arrColWidth[iCount], stretch=True, anchor=arrColAlignment[iCount])
# End of for loop

treeview.pack()

# Row colouring tags
treeview.tag_configure("tgOddRow", background="white")
treeview.tag_configure("tgEvenRow", background="blue")      

# Insert rows
for iCount in range(len(arrRows)):
    if iCount % 2 == 0:
        treeview.insert("", "end", values=arrRows[iCount], tags="tgEvenRow")
    else:
        treeview.insert("", "end", values=arrRows[iCount], tags="tgOddRow")
# End of for loop

objWindow.bind("<Escape>", lambda funcWinSer: objWindow.destroy())

objWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Re-tagging seems like the only solution, IMO

Comment: Instead of moving your column you could configure them with the values you like.

Comment: why do you not want to retag the rows?

Comment: @Atlas435 Guess this is same as retagging

Comment: @BryanOakley How do you propose to solve the problem I posted other than retagging?

Comment: @SandeepSD I dont understand your issue. The possibilities are limited here, either you have static columns which determinates the coloring or not. There seems to be no magical thing that allows you to change without changing.

Comment: @SandeepSD If you prefer you could also have more than one Treeview with different sorted columns and display which ever the user wants to see. I guess there is no more options than these.

Comment: Retagging is the only way to do it. I don't see why that's a problem.

Comment: Thanks to both for your comments. I was wondering if there was a better optimal way to do it other than retagging. I will go with retagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to retag all of the items. The treeview widget can retag a couple thousand rows in a tiny fraction of a second.

Here's a simple example. It assumes you don't have items nested under other items. If you do, it's fairly straightforward to account for that.

```
def retag():
    tag = "tgOddRow"
    for iid in treeview.get_children(""):
        tag = "tgOddRow" if tag == "tgEvenRow" else "tgEvenRow"
        treeview.item(iid, tags=(tag,))
```

When I run that function on a treeview with 10,000 rows, it takes well under 100ms.